# Obtener el link de una imagen con Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Os explico lo que estoy haciendo y lo que quiero hacer, estoy obteniendo la información de una página pero ésta carga las imágenes por javasccript, para conseguirlas hago un post al server para que me devuelva el trozo de html que las contiene. Por alguna razón que se me escapa de mi comprensiónno consigo recojer el link correctamente mediante Xpath, este "html" que me devuelve el servidor:

```
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://www.siie.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://www.siie.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div class="vc_grid vc_row vc_grid-gutter-5px vc_pageable-wrapper vc_hook_hover" data-vc-pageable-content="true"><div class="vc_pageable-slide-wrapper vc_clearfix" data-vc-grid-content="true"><div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4"><div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix "><div class="vc_gitem-animated-block "><div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg') !important;">
    <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165 &#8211; 2 3"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="vc_clearfix"></div></div><div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4"><div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix "><div class="vc_gitem-animated-block "><div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
    <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165-2 1"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="vc_clearfix"></div></div><div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4"><div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix "><div class="vc_gitem-animated-block "><div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
    <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165-2 2"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="vc_clearfix"></div></div><div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4"><div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix "><div class="vc_gitem-animated-block "><div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
    <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165 &#8211; 2 4"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="vc_clearfix"></div></div></div></div>
```

Estos son todos los Xpath que e utilizado pero ninguno con el resultado deseado:

```
        print response.xpath('//a/@href') #no coje todo el link
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//img') #no coje todo el link
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//img[@class=vc_gitem-zone-img]') #vacio
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//*[@class=vc_gitem-zone-img]') #vacio
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//@href') #no coje todo el link
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//@src') #no coje todo el link
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('normalize-space(//a/@href)') #no coje todo el link
        print "-------------------------------------------"
        print response.xpath('//*[@class=vc_gitem-zone-img]/@src') #vacio
```

El último que e usado es este:

```
response.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Y en consola me devuelve el link a medias como los demás:

```
data=u'http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2'>
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, entrecomilla el nombre de las clases, por eso no obtienes coincidencias al usar la clase. En vez de:

```
'//img[@class=vc_gitem-zone-img]'
```

haz:

```
'//img[@class="vc_gitem-zone-img"]'
```

Después, **no imprimas el selector directamente** (instancia de `scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList` posiblemente) si quieres obtener el texto de tus enlaces, usa el método `get` (o su alias `extract_first`) y `getall`(o su alias `extract`) sobre cada selector para obtener el texto completo dependiendo de si solo quisieras la primera coincidencia o todas como es este caso. Si imprimes el objeto obtienes la salida de su método `__str__` (o `__repr__` en su defecto), el cual parece cortar el contenido del atributo `data`, seguramente para facilitar la legibilidad cuando este es muy extenso.

Para generar un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import scrapy


html='''\    
<style type="text/css">
   img.wp-smiley,
   img.emoji {
   display: inline !important;
   border: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   height: 1em !important;
   width: 1em !important;
   margin: 0 .07em !important;
   vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
   background: none !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://www.siie.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://www.siie.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=4.9.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div class="vc_grid vc_row vc_grid-gutter-5px vc_pageable-wrapper vc_hook_hover" data-vc-pageable-content="true">
   <div class="vc_pageable-slide-wrapper vc_clearfix" data-vc-grid-content="true">
      <div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4">
         <div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix ">
            <div class="vc_gitem-animated-block ">
               <div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg') !important;">
                  <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165 &#8211; 2 3"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> 
                  <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4">
         <div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix ">
            <div class="vc_gitem-animated-block ">
               <div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
                  <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165-2 1"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> 
                  <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4">
         <div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix ">
            <div class="vc_gitem-animated-block ">
               <div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
                  <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165-2 2"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> 
                  <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="vc_grid-item vc_clearfix vc_col-sm-4">
         <div class="vc_grid-item-mini vc_clearfix ">
            <div class="vc_gitem-animated-block ">
               <div class="vc_gitem-zone vc_gitem-zone-a vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto vc-gitem-zone-height-mode-auto-1-1 vc_gitem-is-link" style="background-image: url('http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg') !important;">
                  <a href="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg" title="JAGEMBERG 165 &#8211; 2 4"  data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel--1417719797]" data-vc-gitem-zone="prettyphotoLink" class="vc_gitem-link prettyphoto vc-zone-link vc-prettyphoto-link"></a>    <img src="http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg" class="vc_gitem-zone-img" alt=""> 
                  <div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vc_clearfix"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
'''

response = scrapy.Selector(text=html)
```

Ahora solo tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
links = response.xpath('//img[@class="vc_gitem-zone-img"]/@src').getall()
print(links)
```

Lo que muestra la lista con los links para ese html ejemplo:

> ```
> ['http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-3-768x1024.jpeg',
>  'http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-1-1024x768.jpeg',
>  'http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-2-1024x768.jpeg',
>  'http://www.siie.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/JAGEMBERG-165-2-4-1024x768.jpeg']
> ```

Obviamente hay más formas de llegar al elemento.

Comment: Gracias, tendré que fijarme más para la próxima de lo que imprimo y de cómo construyo el Xpath :D